# rewrite css style width plus 10 percent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap. I know there is customize option but I would like to change a small part of element.

the .col is 41% width for example, how can I rewrite it to + 10% in css?

Comment: Why don't you just put in a personnal stylesheet that property : `.col {width:51%}` ? (or it's 10% of 41% that you want ?)

Comment: because it doesn't always 41%, it change according to screen size aka responsive.

Comment: You can, in a personnal stylesheet, rewrite all the size for that col for each screen size ... there's only 4 screen size define in boostrap, it's not a long work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var w=document.getElementById('myElement').style.width;
w = w.replace("%","");
var w2= Math.round(w+ (w/10));

document.getElementById('myElement').style.width=w2+'%';
```